# Unknown record property / related component with multi refs to one table

Tags: symfony1, reference, doctrine

in model definition

```
    $this->hasMany('Photo', array(
         'refClass' => 'StyleLangHasPhoto',
         'local' => 'style_lang_id',
         'foreign' => 'photo_id'));

    $this->hasMany('Photo as Preview', array(
         'refClass' => 'StyleLangHasPreviewPhoto',
         'local' => 'style_lang_id',
         'foreign' => 'photo_id'));
```

but getter `getPreview` and even `$this->_get('Preview')` throws `Unknown record property / related component "Preview" on "StyleLang"`

i've try to make like this

```
    $this->hasMany('Photo as Slide', array(
         'refClass' => 'StyleLangHasPhoto',
         'local' => 'style_lang_id',
         'foreign' => 'photo_id'));

    $this->hasMany('Photo as Preview', array(
         'refClass' => 'StyleLangHasPreviewPhoto',
         'local' => 'style_lang_id',
         'foreign' => 'photo_id'));
```

but nothing changes

what i'm doing wrong?

**UDP1:** getPhoto, setPhoto, setPreview works good

Answer (score 0):

problem was solved

`foreignAlias:` in `relations` for `Photo` and `Preview` must be different

thanx